# What are the commands to get top MISSES and HITS from Varnish 4?

Tags: varnish

For work I am using Varnish 3 on CentOS, but at home I am using Varnish 4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

At work I use these commands:

```
Top hits: varnishtop -i rxurl
Top Misses: varnishtop -i txurl
```

But for some reason they do not work on Varnish 4 Ubuntu.

What are the equivalent of these commands for Varnish 4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Varnish 4

```
varnishtop -i BereqURL
```

will provide you with an updating list of URL requests going to the back-end (Misses).

```
varnishtop -i ReqURL
```

will provide you with an updating list of ALL requests.

I cannot figure out a simple request for a "HIT". The documentation for Varnishtop is at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/varnishtop.html .

(I realise it is not a full answer and I should have left a comment instead but don't have the rep :S )